# Js fonctions only working with index.html

Tags: javascript, html

So i have 2 html pages (index.html and index2.html) and i can't call js function in index2.html .I set up a console.log() in every functions and nothing show up when i try to invoke functions from index2.html . I found nothing in the javascript that could create this issue. Here is my code :
index2.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <input class="example_input" type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="search2">
    <button id="button2" class ="example_button" type="submit" onclick="getvids()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="numofvids2">Nombre de vidéos:</label>
    <select name="Vidsnum2" id="numofvids2">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
    </select>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <h1><span id="vidsdiv2"></span></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js :

```js
function getvids() {
  console.log("getvids")
  var suburl2 = document.getElementById("search2").value;
  var numofvids2 = document.getElementById("numofvids2").value;
  if (suburl2 != "") {
    suburl2 = suburl2.replace(" ", "%20");
    var url2 = 'https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?search='+suburl2+'&page=1&limit='+numofvids2+'&fields=thumbnail_1080_url'
    var request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request2.open('GET', url2);
    request2.responseType = 'json';
    request2.onload = function() {
      var texte2 = request2.response;
      if (texte2.list[0] != undefined) {
        var n2 = 0
        while (texte2.list[n2] != undefined) {
          var allvids2 = allvids2+texte2.list[n2].thumbnail_1080_url+"<br/>";
          n2 = n2+1
        };
        var allvids2 = allvids2.replace("undefined", "")
        document.getElementById("vidsdiv2").innerHTML = allvids2;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("vidsdiv2").innerHTML = "Not found";
      };
    };
    request.send();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("vidsdiv2").innerHTML = "Empty research";
  }
};
```

Comment: It would be helpful when you share your code with us. Have you referenced your js code in in the second html page?

Comment: i added the code

Comment: Jnoasa you answered your question, it would be better when you click on edit above in your question and put the code there

Comment: I did edit now but my question got because I didn't follow the rules i think

Comment: Best technique to write a good question is to set yourself in the position of a person who would like to answer it. Check if you gave all the informations which are necessary to understand the question.